# PHP API endpoint, transmitting value with jQuery.get(..) containing an ampersand (&)

Tags: php, jquery, api, url-encoding, endpoint

I have a simple PHP API endpoint. A possible request could look like this

```
api.php?v1=bob&v2=foo
```

Everything works fine, except when I try to transmit an URL as one of its values, which contains an ampersand:

```
url:      www.bob.com/?v3=bacon&v4=apples
request:  api.php?v1=www.bob.com/?v3=bacon&v4=apples&v2=foo
```

Now obviously this doesn't work, when I try to access `v1` with `$_GET["v1"]` I get `www.bob.com/?v3=bacon`, the part `&v4=apples` is missing because `$_GET` thinks it's another parameter.

So I tried to encode the URL like so:

```
url = encodeURIComponent(url)
```

And transmitting it with jQuery to the endpoint with the following code:

```
$.get("api.php", { v1: url, v2: 'foo'}, function(data, status) {            
    ...
});
```

It still doesn't work.

I assume that jQuery builds the query string as expected and when it gets to the endpoint I got the same mess as before.

What am I missing? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `$.get("api.php", { ... }` should automatically encode the parameters for you.

Comment: @31piy alright I didn't know that, but even if, the result should be the same. Anyhow, I tested it without the `encodeURIComponent`, so just the raw `$.get(..)` with the url as data parameter. Still same problem :/